# Funcion sumar por color con decimales exactos

Tags: vba, color, funcion, decimal, sumatoria

tengo una función aplicada en VBA para que me sume las celdas por color, pero no me devuelve el resultado con los decimales exactos, sino que solo muestra el número entero sin redondear pero con formato Moneda/Contabilidad con ",00". Si por ejemplo el resultado debería ser 132,91€ exacto con decimales, muestra 132,00€.

Muestro a continuación la fórmula aplicada en VBA, a ver si me podéis ayudar a resolverlo.
Muchas gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Estas seguro que el problema es el codigo, y no el formato con el que mostras la salida?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Acostúmbrate a formular las preguntas como indican en los comentarios. Eso es escribiendo tú código directamente en el mensaje y no en una imagen. De otro modo te juegas el que tu pregunta sea cerrada.
Y ahora, tú problema. Prueba a cambiar el tipo de variable de SUMAPORCOLOR a Double:

```
Function Sumarcolor(Celdacolor As Range, Rangosuma As Range) As Double

Dim celda As Range

For Each celda In Rangosuma

If celda.Interior.ColorIndex = Celdacolor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex Then Sumarcolor = Sumarcolor + celda

Next celda

Set celda = Nothing

End Function
```

El tipo de variable Long no toma decimales aunque en el formato de la celda los incluyas.